# unordered_map with self-defined hash function cannot work

Tags: c++, unordered-map, hash-function

I want to use type shared_ptr as the key of an unordered_map. In order to use the **content** of the string as key rather than use the **pointer address**, I define function "hashFn" as hash function. However, code below cannot work. I insert (p1, 0) and then find p2 which has the same content with p1 in the map, but failed. The code print "0".

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto hashFn = [](const shared_ptr<string> &p) -> size_t {
    cout << hash<string>()(*p) << endl;
    return hash<string>()(*p);
  };
  auto map =
      unordered_map<shared_ptr<string>, int, decltype(hashFn)>(0, hashFn);
  auto p1 = shared_ptr<string>(new string("abc"));
  auto p2 = shared_ptr<string>(new string("abc"));
  auto [_it, flag] = map.emplace(p1, 0);
  cout << flag << endl;
  int c = map.count(p2);
  cout << c << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I print the hash result in my hashFn and it shows the result of p1 and p2 is the same. It is confusing...

```cpp
  auto hashFn = [](const shared_ptr<string> &p) -> size_t {
    cout << hash<string>()(*p) << endl;
    return hash<string>()(*p);
  };
```

Comment: Hashes only remove obviously excessive comparisons, but finally map has to check the values for equality. And the values have the "shared_ptr<...>" type, not string. So, here the pointers are comparing and they are different.

Comment: Be *very* careful using the values pointed to as keys. Modifications to the pointed-to-value will break your map: https://godbolt.org/z/aG74bT9rz

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p1` and `p2` are different pointers, so it is natural that `p1` isn't found when searching for `p2`.

Different values can have same hash, so equality of hash doesn't mean equality of values.

If you want to override how to check if keys are equal, you should specify the `equal` argument in the [constructor of `std::unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_map>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  auto hashFn = [](const shared_ptr<string> &p) -> size_t {
    cout << hash<string>()(*p) << endl;
    return hash<string>()(*p);
  };
  auto equalFn = [](const shared_ptr<string> &lhs, const shared_ptr<string> &rhs) -> bool {
    return *lhs == *rhs;
  };
  auto map =
      unordered_map<shared_ptr<string>, int, decltype(hashFn), decltype(equalFn)>(0, hashFn, equalFn);
  auto p1 = shared_ptr<string>(new string("abc"));
  auto p2 = shared_ptr<string>(new string("abc"));
  auto [_it, flag] = map.emplace(p1, 0);
  cout << flag << endl;
  int c = map.count(p2);
  cout << c << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: really helpful! I forgot that hash need to verify the value to avoid collision.